# How to create a json without a tag

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I want to create a json like this:

```
data : { 
        "name" : "abc",
        "age": 23
       }
```

I can write this code:

```
Map<String,Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String,Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.put("name", "abc");
data.put("age", 23);
obj.put("data", data);

String json = new 
 objectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
```

But how can I create a json like this?

```
{ 
  "name" : "abc",
  "age": 23
}
```

Comment: Hmm... `writeValueAsString(data)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you would just need to pass the data instance through rather than the obj instance:

```
Map<String,Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    data.put("name", "abc");
    data.put("age", 23);

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data);
```

In your example above you are creating the tag by inserting the data into another map with key data.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the top level key:

```
Map<String,Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.put("name", "abc");
data.put("age", 23);

String json = new 
 objectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do

```
Map<String,Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<>();
obj.put("name", "abc");
obj.put("age", 23);

String json = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
```